# How to block the navigation in React Router DOM v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In our application, we are showing a modal if the form is not saved with help of history.block() in React Router DOM v5. In the latest version, v6, it's removed. Please find the actual code below. Help me to achieve the same this latest version 6.

Now navigator(NavigationContext) does not expose the block anymore in v6.20.0.

Since the user is allowed to click anywhere on the page, so user is able to move to another page without a prompt.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (show) {
      history.block((prompt, action) => {
        // Define a call back for history.block if the user navigates to any other route
        // action is POP when user hits back button
        if (action !== 'POP') {
          if (!prompt.pathname.includes(match.url) && !ALLOWED_PATHS.includes(prompt.pathname)) {
            setCurrentPath(prompt.pathname);
            setShowPrompt(true);

            return 'true';
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      // defining an empty call back would remove any blocking of route navigation
      history.block(() => {});
    }

    return () => {
      history.block(() => {});
    };
  }, [history, show, match.url, ALLOWED_PATHS]);
```